# To color a limited number of lines in git log --oneline

Tags: git, head

When I pipe a git command to head to display only a few dozens of commits, the colors are lost:

```
git log --oneline | head -50
```

How to keep colors with a limited number of lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-(n) Show only the last n commits

Ref : https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Grunnleggende-Git-Viewing-the-Commit-History

For exemple

```
git log -50 --oneline
```

Comment: I prefer this one because it better matches the intent

Answer (score 4):

Git detects that you're piping to something, so it disables color, but you can force it to use color with `--color`:

```
git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate --color | head -50
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using -50 as a parameter in your git log command?

It will show the newest 50 commits.

You can also write

- --max-count=50
- -n 50
- -n50
- -50